# Flutter generateJsonModelDebug while using ffi contained library

Tags: android, flutter, cmake, dart-ffi

I want to use flutter library that contains dart FFI for performance.
Library name is bitmap and document says nothing special setting required to use.
So I added `bitmap: ^0.0.6` to pubspec.yaml and build it.
But build error came out and it says:

```
Execution failed for task ':bitmap:generateJsonModelDebug'.
> exception while building Json $Cannot run program  
 "/Users/choeseungmin/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/cmake": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Is there anything to do before I use FFI contained library?
Or How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I find out a solution.
Go Android studio's `sdk manager > delete Cmake and NDK(android C++ related)` and reinstall those deleted contents again and it works.